# How to bit shift hex value using Golang?

Tags: go, hex, bit-manipulation

Let's say I have a string with the value of `4ADDF6C259EBAFF8`.

Using this I want to get a timestamp, using the formula `(hex(val) >> 25) + 1008000400`.

Using t he `encoding/hex` package, I have come up with the following:

```
srcBytes := []byte(src)
dst := make([]byte, hex.EncodedLen(len(srcBytes)))
hex.Encode(dst, srcBytes)
```

After this, I need a way to bit shift `dst` 25 times, and then add a constant to it.

However `dst` is of type `[]byte`.

I need it to be of type `hex` so I can bit shift after. How do I convert `[]byte` so that it can be shifted?

Comment: What does it mean to "bit shift" a hex value? That is just a base 16 textual representation of a number. You can of course hex encode the final value. https://play.golang.org/p/O-nrvJl4J2j

Comment: `hex.Encode` turns bytes into the hex string representing those bytes, which sounds like the opposite of what you're trying to do; you can't bit shift a string. There is no "type `hex`" in Go. Hex is just a way of representing bytes as alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Based on the description, it *seems like* what you want to do is turn your hex string into bytes (using `hex.Decode`), turn the bytes into an `int64` (using `encoding/binary`), and then do your math (the bit shift and addition).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input string varies but has a maximum of 16 hex digits, you just convert to a 64 bit (unsigned) integer and do the math. I also prefixed your constant with *0x* assuming it is hex (judging by the digits).

```
  s := "4ADDF6C259EBAFF8"
  if i, err := strconv.ParseUint(s, 16, 64); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", i >> 25 + 0x1008000400)
  }
```

BTW *hex* is not a type but a way of displaying integers.

Comment: According to the question 1008000400 is a decimal number, not hexadecimal. Also, [indent error handling](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#indent-error-flow), not the "normal" flow.

Comment: Thanks @Peter you are probably right. I thought that it was very likely that it was hex myself judging by the fact that the question is about bit fiddling and the number has just 3 bits set if it's hex but has 14 bits set if it's decimal. His expression implies that it is decimal but he does *not* state that. My gut instinct is that he made a mistake and it's hex. However, I added a sentence of explanation in case I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for the info about the indenting of error-handling code. I actually do that.  Sorry the above code was just an example not a complete well-designed sample.  I even considered not adding the error-handling for simplicity but though it better to add just as a reminder not to skip it.

Comment: Seeing 25 bits discarded right away, one is better off discarding the last 6 characters of the hex value and shifting by 25-(6*4) = 1. Allows to handle 22 place hex numbers...